# How to use external power supply for a Proximity Sensor with Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, microcontroller, arduino-uno

Is it doable to read a proximity sensor values with Arduino Uno, but the sensor requires 24vdc, here's the sensor [link](https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B008DG9DLU/ref=dp_olp_0?ie=UTF8&condition=all)

and here's the power supply I'd like to use, this [link](http://www.jameco.com/z/RT-50D-Mean-Well-AC-to-DC-Power-Supply-Triple-Output-5-Volt-24-Volt12-Volt-5-Amp-1-5-Amp-1-Amp-51-Watt_323476.html)

This is all for learning purposes, to see how to use an external power source to power a 3-wire 24vdc sensor

Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: Instead of posting the relevant code in links, please include them in the question itself. Useful link: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

the power supply voltage of the sensor dosnt matter,  only the signal potential matters. Ardunio analog pins needs the input potential between - 5 to +5v so make sure the signal potential lies in between this. One thing to take care while using an external power supply is to make ext and ardunio's ground common.

Comment: Thanks for the answer nithin, how can I find out about the sensor's signal potential?? is that something needs to be mentioned in the sensor's data sheet??

and about commonizing GND of external power supply and Arduino's, is the an example , a wiring diagram that you can share?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing this for learning purpose you don't have to waste money on that power supply. You can power the probe from arduino if you want so. But you have to take care of these things.

1)Curent consuption
As per this [pr12-4dp-autonics-12800368](http://datasheet.octopart.com/PR12-4DP-Autonics-datasheet-8621788.pdf) datasheet which is similar to the device you are using the current requirement of the device is 10mA which an arduino uno can provide (40mA is max for arduino uno) check your device data sheet for its current consumption.

2)voltage level
Arduino uno power out pins support 5 volts and 3.3 volts. so you have to convert the 5 volt to required volts with help of voltage converter ICs (for example LM2577 IC). check whether the IC you chose supports the current required by the sensor.

3)Input signal logic level from the sensor
This you can do with voltage converter ICs or an humble [voltage divider circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider).

If you are using the external power supply you have to take care of only 3rd step.

Comment: The 10 mA drawn will be at 24 volts. If you are providing 24 volts from a 5 volt power supply, then 10 * 24 / 5 = 48 mA, more than you say Arduino can supply.

Comment: Investing in a good quality power supply for bench electronics cannot be called a waste of money.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer Nithin P, highly appreciated, the thing is I'm trying to create a program  using .NET with C++ , the idea eventually is power up more than one of these sensors, that's why I thought about using such power supply, I'll definitely consider your input